# react redux-thunk component doesn't render this.props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, jsx, redux-thunk

I'm new to react and I'm trying to understand on to make async ajax request. I was able to get the request completed and the data returned added to my state, but I can't render the data to my component. Here's my setup.

#### UserPage component

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { getUsers } from '../../actions';

class User extends Component {
    displayName: 'User';

    componentWillMount() {
        this.props.getUsers();
    }

    renderUsers() {
        return this.props.users.map(user => {
            return (
                <h5>{user.Name}</h5>
            );
        });
    }

    render() {
        var component;
        if (this.props.users) {
            component = this.renderUsers()
        } else {
            component = <h3>asdf</h3>;
        }

        return (            
            <div>
                {component}
            </div>

        );
    };
};

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        users: state.all
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getUsers })(User);
```

#### Action

```js
import request from '../helpers/request';
import { GET_USERS } from './types';

export function getUsers() {

    return request.get(GET_USERS, 'Person/GetPeople');
}
```

With the get function from request.js module

```js
get: function (action, url) {
        return (dispatch) => {
            axios.get(`${ROOT_URL}${url}`)
                .then(({ data }) => {
                    dispatch({
                        type: action,
                        payload: data
                    });
                });
        };
    }
```

#### User_reducer

```js
import { GET_USERS } from '../actions/types';

export default function (state = {}, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case GET_USERS:
            console.log(action);
            return { ...state, all: action.payload }
        default:
            return state;
    };
}
```

When I load the UserPage component, I can see the request being done and the state being updated in the redux dev tool, but I can't display this.props.users.

If I take out the if(this.props.users) in the render() method of the User component, I get an undefined on this.props.users.

What am I doing wrong?

Any help greatly appreciated! Thank you

## SOLVED

The solution was to set the users property to state.users.all in the mapStateToProps function.

```js
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        users: state.users.all
    };
}
```

Thank you

Comment: In your render function at the place of {component}, try {JSON.stringify(this.props.users)}. Make sure the users data is coming to render function.

Comment: @Prakashsharma There's nothing since the users property is undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you check, do you have `this.renderUsers()` defined in that render function? It might be you forgot to bind it, and that function is `undefined`?

Try to add `this.renderUsers = this.renderUsers.bind(this);` in your constructor and see, if it helps.

Comment: Tried it, but it didn't work.
If I remove the `if (this.props.users)`, I get the error I mentionned before:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Comment: Hm, strange. I've made webpackbin with code almost exactly like yours, and it works (wait for two seconds while 'request' resolves): https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-KgVx4Jdtgw2v7CU6WXj

Maybe you can spot and issue? Because i can't :)

Comment: Thank you so much for you example, it helped me figured it out.
The problem was that in my `mapStateToProps(state)` function, I set the users property to `state.all` instead of `state.users.all`.

Really appreciate your help!