# Redux + Thunk + Axios + Consume external API: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined"

Tags: api, react-redux, axios, redux-thunk

I am just starting with Redux and External APIs. For learning, I wanted to consume API from NASA (https://api.nasa.gov/). I don't know what I do wrong. I can't render anything on screen. I get "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined" in the console.

I've read several Q&A in stackoverflow... But I didn't find out where is the problem in my code.

I'd really appreciate any opinion. I need a clue... Thanks in advance.

[image]

**CONTAINER**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { showTutusers } from '../actions/index';
import { bindActionCreators } from "redux";

class TutuserListContainer extends Component {

  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.showTutusers()
  }

  render() {
    return (

      <div>     
           <h3> { this.props.tutusers.photos[0].id}</h3><br />
           <h3> { this.props.tutusers.photos[1].id}</h3><br />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    tutusers: state.tutuser.tutusers
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { showTutusers })(TutuserListContainer)
```

**REDUCERS - INDEX**

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';
import { showTutusers } from './tutusers'


const allReducers = combineReducers({
    tutuser: showTutusers, 
});

export default allReducers
```

**REDUCER**

```
import { FETCH_TUTUSERS_START, FETCH_TUTUSERS_ERROR, RECEIVED_TUTUSERS } from '../actions/action-types';

const initialState = {
    fetching: false,
    fetched: false,
    tutusers: [],
    error: null
}

export function showTutusers(state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case FETCH_TUTUSERS_START: {
            return {...state, fetching: true}
            break; 
        }
        case FETCH_TUTUSERS_ERROR: {
            return {...state, fetching: false, error: action.payload}
            break; 
        }
        case RECEIVED_TUTUSERS: {
            return {...state, fetching: false, fetched: true, tutusers: action.payload}
            break; 
        }
    }
    return state

}
```

**ACTION-TYPES**

```
    export const SHOW_TUTUSERS = 'SHOW_TUTUSERS';
    export const FETCH_TUTUSERS_START = 'FETCH_TUTUSERS_START';
    export const FETCH_TUTUSERS_ERROR = 'FETCH_TUTUSERS_ERROR';
    export const  RECEIVED_TUTUSERS = ' RECEIVED_TUTUSERS';
```

**ACTIONS - INDEX**

```
import * as types from '../actions/action-types';
import axios from 'axios';
import store from '../stores/store';

export function showTutusers() {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        store.dispatch( { type: types.FETCH_TUTUSERS_START} ) 
        axios.get('https://api.nasa.gov/mars-photos/api/v1/rovers/curiosity/photos?sol=1000&api_key=_____MY_KEY____')
            .then((response) => {
                store.dispatch( { type: types.RECEIVED_TUTUSERS, payload: response.data } ) 
               // console.log(">>> response.data", response.data)             
            }) 
            .catch((err) => {
                dispatch({type: "FETCH_TUTUSERS_ERROR", payload: err})
            })
    }

}
```

**STORE**

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import allReducers from '../reducers';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
// import promise from 'redux-promise';
import createLogger from 'redux-logger';
import promise from 'redux-promise-middleware';

const middleware = applyMiddleware(thunk, promise(), createLogger());

const store = createStore(
    allReducers,
    compose(middleware, window.devToolsExtension ? window.devToolsExtension() : f => f)
);

export default store;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait until the response is received and only then try to access the photos, something like this should help:

```
 <div> 
   {this.props.tutusers.fetched && <div>    
       <h3> { this.props.tutusers.photos[0].id}</h3><br />
       <h3> { this.props.tutusers.photos[1].id}</h3><br />
  </div>}
</div>
```

You also need to pass all the data about the request:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    tutusers: state.tutuser
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response @Shota. I included your suggestion. Now no error appears, but nothing is rendered on screen. Any clue? BTW, I already have in my container.

Comment: Could you `console.log` what `this.props.tutusers` contains?

Comment: Hi @Shota. If I console log Initially, an empty array, later: `Object {photos: Array(856)}`If I click on it:
`photos
:
Array(856)` If I click on it: 
`[0 … 99]` If I click on it, you'll see the data of the objects. Basically what you can see in my previous screenshot.

Comment: If I console log **this.props.tutusers.photos** initially I get **undefined** and few seconds later I get:  **[Object, Object, Object...]**. But if I console log **this.props.tutusers.photos[1]** I get **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined**, and nothing changes few seconds later instead.

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution in this  stackoverflow question: [react redux-thunk component doesn't render this.props](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43126987/react-redux-thunk-component-doesnt-render-this-props)

Basically I only needed an **if else** statement:

```
render() {
        var component;
        if (this.props.tutusers) {
            component = this.functionToRenderTutusers()
        } else {
            component = <h3>Loading...</h3>;
        }
        return (            
            <div>
                {component}
            </div>
        );
    };
```

---

```
 functionToRenderTutusers() {
    return this.props.tutusers.photos.map((tutuser) => {
      return (
         <div>{tutuser.id}</div>
      )
    })
 }
```